# How can I make peristent changes on a USB ubuntu install?

Tags: live-usb, persistence

Here's what I've tried with no success:

- Unetbootin: It keeps hanging.
- [Linux Live USB](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/): I only get an empty folder as the result
- Universal installer: it hasn't worked.

Can I use my Ubunu CD-ROM in persistent mode?

Comment: Weird because my mom has the same model and it has worked since 11.10. And only using the livecd it still works.

Comment: Please only ask one question in any post. Yo can edit your post and create a new one for the 2nd problem.

Comment: Please Luis Can you tell me what to do please I have been trying for the last week please Luis

Comment: but I feel  the questions are related to one problem under one topic anyway I just want the printer to work  Luis has already replied and said its work with just the  live cd so it turns out I just need help with the printer and hopefully Luis will help me as his mum as the same printer which works of the live cd

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot do this with a LiveCD**

CDs, for the most part, are designed to be read-only once they've been written to. Even rewritable CDs typically require CD writing software, because most other applications will see the disk as a standard CD and assume it's read-only. This means that you cannot save your printer setup to the LiveCD.

**You can install Ubuntu to a USB thumb drive**

It's actually deceptively easy - take a standard live CD and boot to it with your USB drive plugged in, and install Ubuntu to the USB drive like you would to any other hard drive (be sure that everything points to the USB drive). You can then boot to it by selecting the USB drive in the boot device selection menu when your computer boots up. This method does format the drive to Ext4, so Windows can no longer read it, but it makes the entire drive available to the Ubuntu install, just as though it were on a regular hard drive.

**Your printer driver issues aren't all related to your LiveCD issues**

A 500 error is an error coming from the server that Ubuntu is trying to download from. It means that something is wrong with the server itself. There's nothing you can do about that error from that download mirror for that particular driver, except wait a while (anywhere from a few minutes to a couple of days) and see if it comes back. However, the LaserJet 1000 series is old enough that you should have a generic driver option available, which should allow you to install it. If that option isn't available, or doesn't work, then simply download it directly from the [HPLIP website](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html) (it also includes instructions on installing it manually).

Saving the settings, of course, will require a writable medium, which I've addressed above.

Comment: With the cd are you saying insert the ubuntu live cd ? Yes but I do t know how to even use the terminal for installing hplip it keep saying command not recognised I need serious help I feel lost in a stack of needles I need specific instruction I tried following hplip I download excited the file in ubuntu and says error then say smooth want to retry then comes back error retry I press y for yes comes back error please advise me its hell

Comment: when you said take a standard live cd I take it your meaning take the ubuntu cd  put in my pc boot from cd rom which the usb drive is plugged in at the same time  ubuntu has now started I go to start disk creator its now asking me where the ubuntu ISO is located at in which path? I don't have room to download another copy as the live cd of ubuntu is only 700mb

Comment: @UbuntuRokz - You don't ust the start disk creator for what I've described. And remember, you have to have a USB drive plugged in as well. You then find the "Install Ubuntu" shortcut (if the CD doesn't prompt you, or you've closed the prompt) and install it just like you would to a regular hard drive.

Comment: but it install straight to hard disk and will install it to hard drive rather then disk drive or does it give an option to install straight to usb thanks for bearing with me

Comment: @UbuntuRokz - If you want better quality help, you're going to need to work on your posts. I know you're probably frustrated, but we can't help you if your questions and responses are incoherent. I noticed that you created a separate question for your printer issues. That's good. I recommend editing that question with the specific steps you've taken and error messages you've received (copy and paste, and/or screenshots work well).

Comment: so dva/sdaI will install to that and it will be install to flash disk

Comment: @UbuntuRokz - The installer is a setup wizard, just like any other program you've installed. It will give you a choice of where to install to before it starts anything. As long as you have a USB drive plugged in, it will detect it and give you the option to install to it.

Comment: @UbuntuRokz - you should try and tackle the problem with HP printer plugin later, after you have a working Ubuntu OS where you can store your settings and data using either of these 2 methods: 1) Create live USB with persistence OR 2) Install Ubuntu on USB.

Comment: ok so it will know I want to usb and not wipe the whole hard drive with someone else operating system thanks shauna

Comment: will only install on usb be a persistent install the method you gave Shauna?

Comment: Shauna will you method you just described above be a persistent method or I will have to try and do what Sadie said

Comment: even I I use your method number 2 it won't save my printer setting the next time round will it?

Comment: the commands are not working when I'm typing to install hplip no such directory sh-hplip.run no such premisiin I'm doing this from live cd

Comment: are you still here

Comment: ok lets tacle printer after will method 2 allow me to save my printer settings

Comment: thankful Shauna I have re read your post and install to usb should allow me to save my printer settings as the  usb is rewritable right? Doing your method will make it seem like the  usb is a hard drive install  w

installing ubantu this way

Comment: @UbuntuRokz - The comments here are not for chat. That said, yes, installing to the USB drive the way that I've instructed will make it persistent.

Comment: Thankful will you help me with my printer setup after this please. Also I'm new so I don't know how the forum works it saying do you want to move this to chat shall I move it to chat?? What does that do anyway move discussion to chat? The comments are not here for chat what did you mean by that.?. Will you help me with my printer after I have made a ubuntu usb  please

Comment: @UbuntuRokz - [The FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) has the information about what's expected here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a **Live USB** for persistence as live CD cannot store your settings and data.

And for this you can simply use Ubuntu's own **Startup Disk Creator** or [MultiSystem](http://liveusb.info/dotclear/index.php?pages/install).

Comment: But I'm using windows

Comment: But you should be able to boot your computer from live CD and start using Ubuntu (without installing)

Comment: I never said I could not boot from cd?

Comment: So, if you couldn't somehow create a live USB with persistence using Windows programs, what I suggested was that you can perhaps boot your computer from Ubuntu live CD and try the above-mentioned Linux programs to create Ubuntu live USB with persistence.

Comment: Genius dude I will do just that Thankful so much Thankful sir

Comment: Slight problem the ubuntu live cd I have is 700mb how do I download another copy of Bantu not enough romm

Comment: not enough room I started usb creator in ubuntu live cd its asking for the ubuntu ISO I can download another ubuntu on this cd as its only 700mb so how do I make a start up cd from with in ubuntu using just the ubuntu live cd of 700mb

Comment: 1) You can try and use the Ubuntu ISO which you probably used to write your live CD and which is probably somewhere on your HDD (Ubuntu live CD session should be able to access it)
2) You can download Ubuntu ISO anywhere other than your CD-ROM and use it as above.

Comment: but its in the windows section of some one else computer I'm using ubuntu live cd  can't access windows files from live cd?

Comment: really how do you download it anywhere. Where in the past I tried downloading ubuntu and its most certainly told me not enough spacesuits to the cd only being 7 00mb I'm interested in which method you are saying where it can download it any where are your saying it will download it in the windows directory from with a ubuntu live cd? Quite interested to know this answer

Comment: are you still here?

Comment: When you try to download an ISO file in a live CD session, you'll see Firefox dialog box prompting you if you'd like to Open or Save the file, and there's also a Browse... button which allows you to choose a location to save the downloaded file. While browsing you can choose any drive, partition, folder available on your PC. But you should be able to access/use an ISO file in the Windows drive/partition/folder with no harm at all.

Comment: Thankful so much said so what your saying is I can so I download the ubuntuniso in windows then start ubuntu live cd then go to startup disk creator and from there you saying  will be able to select the ubuntu ISO that in the windows download folder  ?.?

Comment: is it like file system then browse to windows hdd with in Bantu and I see ubuntu ISO sitting in windows folder from within Bantu live cd?

Comment: Yes, the Startup Disk Creator should enable you to use ISO file from anywhere in the computer. I've never tried it but you might even be able to use your live CD as the source to create a live USB.

Comment: btw do you know why usb live linux had finishing making the usb but then when I went into the folder it was totally empty when there should have been the virtual machine folder that's what live usb is suppose to make that type of usb with in windows? Why is folder than empy?

Comment: what went wrong btw when I make the usb will yo helpt me install the hplp  pacakge

Comment: I cannot tell much about Windows programs as I've stopped using Windows for some years now ;-) But logically linux programs should be better at creating a live linux system. And you should have a better chance of having a successful HP configuration when you run live USB with persistence.

Comment: ok Thankyou Sadi Thankful very much dude Thanks for all your help